# How to load CSV file in Redis using node-Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-modules, node-redis

I am on windows 10 machine. I have a csv file with 0.5 million records in it. I want that csv file to be read by some streaming and load the data inside it in Redis using node-redis. We can use Redis Sets or Hashes for this.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');  
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

client.on('connect', function() {
console.log('Redis client connected');
});

client.on('error', function (err) {
console.log('Something went wrong ' + err);
 });

fs.createReadStream('test.csv')  
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (row) => {
 console.log(row);
})
.on('end', () => {
 console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
});
```

Comment: How does your csv data look like? What is physically present in it? Do you want a set or hash?

Comment: @Avanthika My csv looks like this 
 `"nameofOrganization","ip_org","domain","db_add_date","db_update_date","created_by",
"MaxHealthInsurance",192.68.1.1,"Insurance",23-08-2018,12-09-2018,"Alex"
`

Comment: @Avanthika I want set